# String extracting in C

Tags: c, json

Below the JSMN Library implementation. Where it searches for "command", "rf_type" and "Filter" in incoming JSON message. Now the program automatically prints the extracted strings. I need to pass it to another variable and use the string in another function.

start->Extract command from JSON->pass to another function->end

Any one can guide how to take the string printed to variable in this case

```
 printf("===============================\n");
 for (i = 1; i < r; i++) {

        if (jsoneq(JSON_STRING, &t[i], "command") == 0) 
        {

        printf("- command: %.*s\n", t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start,
                JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start);
        i++;
        } 

        else if (jsoneq(JSON_STRING, &t[i], "rf_type") == 0) 

        {

        printf("- rf_type: %.*s\n", t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start,
                JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start);
        i++;
        }
        else if (jsoneq(JSON_STRING, &t[i], "filter") == 0) 

        {

        printf("- filter: %.*s\n", t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start,
                JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start);
        i++;
        }

        else 
        {
        printf("Unexpected messages HUB_HCI: %.*s\n", t[i].end-t[i].start,
                JSON_STRING + t[i].start);
        }
}
return 1;
```

Comment: You can [`sprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) (or `snprintf` if you have a C99 implementation) to "print" to a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full function implementation for receiving message and comparing.

```
int msgarrvd(void *context, char *topicName, int topicLen,MQTTClient_message *message)
{
 int i;
char* payloadptr;
char *test[256];
printf("Message arrived\n");
printf("topic: %s\n", topicName);
printf("===============================\n");

payloadptr = message->payload;
for(i=0; i<message->payloadlen; i++)
{
    JSON_STRING[i]=*payloadptr++;
    //putchar(*payloadptr++);
printf("%c", JSON_STRING[i]);
}
putchar('\n');
MQTTClient_freeMessage(&message);
MQTTClient_free(topicName);

    jsmn_init(&p);
r = jsmn_parse(&p, JSON_STRING, strlen(JSON_STRING), t, sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]));
if (r < 0) {
    printf("Failed to parse JSON: %d\n", r);
}


if (r < 1 || t[0].type != JSMN_OBJECT) {
    printf("Not Valid JSON-HCI_HUB\n");
}

printf("===============================\n");
for (i = 1; i < r; i++) {

        if (jsoneq(JSON_STRING, &t[i], "command") == 0) 
        {

        printf("- command: %.*s\n", t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start,
                JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start);
        test[256]=t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start,JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start;
        printf("%s\n",&test);
        i++;
        } 

        else if (jsoneq(JSON_STRING, &t[i], "rf_type") == 0) 

        {

        printf("- rf_type: %.*s\n", t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start,
                JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start);
        i++;
        }
        else if (jsoneq(JSON_STRING, &t[i], "filter") == 0) 

        {

        printf("- filter: %.*s\n", t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start,
                JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start);
        i++;
        }

        else 
        {
        printf("Unexpected messages HUB_HCI: %.*s\n", t[i].end-t[i].start,
                JSON_STRING + t[i].start);
        }
}
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    else 
    {
    printf("Unexpected messages HUB_HCI: %.*s\n", t[i].end-t[i].start,
            JSON_STRING + t[i].start);
    }
```

Looks very suspicious to me
I'd expect

```
    else 
    {
    printf("Unexpected messages HUB_HCI: %.*s\n", t[i].end-t[i].start,
            (const char *) t[i].start);
    }
```

Why add the JSON_STRING enum type constant to a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [tiny-json](https://github.com/rafagafe/tiny-json). It is not only a tokenizer. You can get data in string format or get the primitives values in C type variables without performance loss.

You can use in two ways. You can get the JSON fields one on one.

```
    char str[] = "{\"command\":\"qwerty\",\"rf_type\":2,\"filter\":\"low pass\",\"unexpected\":\"hello\"}";       
    puts( str );

    json_t pool[5];
    json_t const* root = json_create( str, pool, 5 );

    if ( root ) {

        json_t const* field = json_getChild( root );
        while( field ) {                
                char const* name  = json_getName( field );
                char const* value = json_getValue( field );

                if ( !strcmp( name, "command") )
                    printf("- command: %s\n", value );

                else if ( !strcmp( name, "rf_type") )
                    printf("- rf_type: %s\n", value );

                else if ( !strcmp( name, "filter") )
                    printf("- filter: %s\n", value );

                else 
                    printf("Unexpected message. Name: '%s', Value: '%s'.\n", name,value );

                field = json_getSibling( field );
        }            
    }
```

Or get their values by their names. This helps you to save a lot of source code lines and development time.

```
char str[] = "{\"command\":\"qwerty\",\"rf_type\":2,\"filter\":\"low pass\"}";
puts( str );

json_t pool[4];
json_t const* root = json_create( str, pool, 4 );

if ( root ) {

    char const* command = json_getPropertyValue( root, "command" );
    if ( command ) printf("- command: %s\n", command );

    char const* rf_type = json_getPropertyValue( root, "rf_type" );
    if ( rf_type ) printf("- rf_type: %s\n", rf_type );

    char const* filter = json_getPropertyValue( root, "filter" );
    if ( filter ) printf("- filter: %s\n", filter );        
}
```

If you want to keep the json properties in text you have to make a string copy with strcpy().